# How to accept both multipart and application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: java, jquery, http, servlets

I built a servlet that allows uploading a file or alternatively uploading a list as input. So far I've handled it by setting the servlet to accept multipart/form-data so even if there is no file, I read the list as a part.

I'm now trying to call this servlet to upload a list through a JQuery AJAX method instead of through a form. If I try to upload a list normally through the method, I get:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

If I set the contentType as multipart/form-data like so:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: someUrl, 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data', 
    data: {list: inputList}
});
```

I get this error instead:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

My question is if there is some way to configure the servlet to accept both content types or alternatively is there some way to write the ajax data to upload multipart/form-data?

I know it's simple to upload multipart/form-data using the FormData API, but I need to support IE9 so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) library. It provides you with a uniform interface, no matter which type of form was submitted, and makes it easy to work with uploaded files. See Section *Processing the uploaded items* of the [User Guide](https://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html), it should give you a general idea how it works.

Comment: I'm not sure FileUpload handles url-encoded forms. When trying to parse a url-encoded form, FileUpload will throw following exception: "the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded".